# Does stress level goes down or up while sleeping?

Tags: sleep, depression, stress

Given we are in the same situations, same circumstances and a person is able to sleep fine without any issues.

Are we more stressful at night while we are sleeping or during day when we are up in comparison to each other?

I personally think stress level should go down when people sleep due to resting & restoring but I am not a doctor.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103867/discussion-on-question-by-zar-does-stress-level-goes-down-or-up-while-sleeping).